# Why would I add CommandType in Query method?

Tags: c#, repository, dapper

Consider the following codes:

```
public List<Author> Read()
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection
          (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorks"].ConnectionString))
           {
            string readSp = "GetAllAuthors";
            return db.Query<Author>(readSp,commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
           }
    }
```

Why would the example adds `commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure` in the return?

Is it for anti-SQL-injection?

I get the example here: http://www.infoworld.com/article/3025784/application-development/how-to-work-with-dapper-in-c.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell the query that it is a StoredProcedure.
Also try to look on this MSDN documentation [CommandType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SQLCommand CommandType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I know that is for telling the Dapper to use Stored Procedure but what is the benefit?

Comment: It will be used for creating a new instance of CommandDefinition then passing the CommandType to IDbCommand for executing the query. Basically it used to determine how the query to be executed.

Comment: So if I remove the CommandType the only change is the query will be executed different way. Is it still safe to remove the CommandType?

Comment: Yes, it will just use it default value.

Comment: If you remove the command type, a different query will be executed. As it stands, this executes a stored a procedures with a name of `GetAllAuthors`. If you remove those parameters, you'll be executing generated SQL rather than a pre-written stored procedure.